# Query for JSON String using JdbcTemplate to neo4j?

Tags: json, jdbc, neo4j, jdbctemplate

I want to use a JdbcTemplate and the Neo4j JDBC driver to query my neo4j database and return a JSON string.

Is there an existing method to do this?

I've googled and I can't find one.

It otherwise looks like a matter of [creating a home cooked RowMapper as per here.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

```
The query :
MATCH (s:Site) - [r] - (ss:SiteState) return s,ss;

it return a json but for my use i use an object 

public class SiteRowMapper implements RowMapper<Site> {

    @Override
    public Site mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Site site = new Site();
        SiteState siteState = new SiteState();
        Gson json = new Gson();
        site = json.fromJson(rs.getString("s"), Site.class);
        siteState = json.fromJson(rs.getString("ss"), SiteState.class);
        site.setName(siteState.getName());
        return site;
    }

}
```